# Python Beautiful Soup web scraping CNN election results

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Please bear with me I am brand new to web scraping! I want to scrape all of the exit poll data off this CNN webpage http://www.cnn.com/election/results/exit-polls
for this question I will just ask to scrape the first exit poll, the gender one. 
the code below doesnt print anything. what I am doing wrong? not looping through all the tags?

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.cnn.com/election/results/exit-polls').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find("div",{"class":"exit-poll__question"})
print table
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup can't get that information since the information is loaded using Javascript.

Comment: ahh so what would I need to use?

Comment: Take a look at something like [dryscrape](https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape). There's a good example of usage [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26440563/7090605).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find the data in this [link](http://data.cnn.com/ELECTION/2016/US/xpoll/Pfull.json)

you can find the link in chrome's dev-tools>>Network

so what you need to do is to request the url

i hope this will help.